# DataFrame Indexing with a date series

Tags: python, date, pandas

I'm new to Python and Pandas, and am having some trouble indexing by a date series.  I am trying to pull data into a DataFrame from a SQLite db that consists of a date in format 'mm/dd/yyyy' and an equity price.  I then create a new DataFrame using set_index to index the prices by the dates.  How can I set the new index as a dateseries using the dates from my dataset? Does this require a datetime conversion or does DataFrame have the ability to convert from an object to a dateseries?

Below is the code I am using:

```
import sqlite3 as db
import pandas as p

dbcon = db.connect(...ETF_DATA_TEST.db)
c = dbcon.cursor()
c.execute(""" QUERY """)
rs =p.DataFrame.from_records(c.fetchall(),columns =['Date','Price'])
data = rs.set_index('Date')
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? release version 0.8 ( http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html ) changed handling of datetime from object types to numpy datetime64 types, so they have full datetime functionality starting with that release

Comment: Currently using an older version, 0.7.3

Comment: All set now, updated to the latest Pandas version and have set it using DatetimeIndex().  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @KRaphael Why don't you post your comment as an answer so the OP MattB can mark this as resolved and give you your due credit?

Answer (score 0):

You can use datetime.datetime.strptime to parse your 'Date' strings and then construct numpy.datetime64 values from the datetime.datetime types:

```
data = rs.reindex(numpy.array([(lambda x : datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y'))(x) for x in rs['Date']],dtype='datetime64[us]')
```